# How to cash in State of California tax refund cheque outside the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, check, refund

I worked in the US last year and filed my taxes (or more specifically, had it filed with the help of a tax agency I was given from my employer).

Now I've received a cheque which looks like this:
[Refund cheque](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2aqn.jpg)

I've closed my US bank account after leaving the US, and I live in Germany right now (I am a German citizen).

Do you know how I can cash this cheque outside the US? Is it considered a "standard" check which I can just cash at my banks (I would normally just walk over, but given Covid-19 that's a bit difficult here right now - I might be asked to send them in via mail and obviously only would like to do that if they let me really cash it) or do I have to do something different?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you asked your German bank if they can accept a US dollar cheque?

Comment: Assuming the check is legitimate you shouldn't have issues depositing the check into your account (with horrendous currency exchange fees taken out). But again, this is an assumption and no one but your bank will be able to tell you definitively

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. I'll figure it out - as mentioned I would have gone to my bank already if they had regular business right now, which they don't have due to Covid19

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you managed to cash the cheque in Germany? In which bank?